# google sheet : combine 2 set of data using query formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have this tables :

[image]

A/B are the sources and C is the goal (final output) after combining. I have 2 sets of data (A and B) and I want to use query() formula to replace the data on B. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

*You may try this on your test data (`non-query approach`):*

```js
=let(Σ,E4:E,
 arrayformula(hstack(Σ,xlookup(Σ,B:B,C:C,xlookup(Σ,E:E,F:F,)))))
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly but I need the query method because in my real case both A and B are query() output with no column address such as E:E or F:F.